# Class imbalance and "all zeros" one-hot encoding?

Tags: supervised-learning

I tried [this](https://androidkt.com/multi-label-text-classification-in-tensorflow-keras/) example for a multi class classifier, but when looking at the data I realized two things:

1. There are many examples of "all zeros" vectors, that is, messages that don't belong in any classification.
2. These all-zeros are actually the majority, by far.

Is it valid to have an all-zeros output for a certain input? I would guess a Sigmoid activation would have no problems with this, by simply not trying to force a one out of all the "near zero" outputs.

But I also think an "accuracy" metric will be skewed too optimistically: if all outputs are zero 90% of the time, the network will quickly overfit to always output 0 all the time, and get 90% score.

Comment: are you sure that this is not an effect of processing mistake to have all zeros?

Comment: also if you have all zeros in training data so maybe add additional column that will be = 1 when this situation happens else 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your questions as follows:

**Is it valid to have an all-zeros output for a certain input?**

Yes its possible in some cases like:

1. In the tutorial "jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge", the data is taken from wikipedia comments, so generally there is no toxic behavior in people's comment, it is very rare that a person posts "bad" comments in an informative source like wikipedia, this might lead to all the labels being zero for a particular example.
2. In a single label classification like predicting whether a person has a rare disease,the dataset would contain labels that are mostly "zero"-(no disease)-skewed towards zero

This happens in datasets where the positive output to be predicted is a very rare case.

**I guess your second question is -whether "accuracy" is a good way of evaluating a model for this type of a problem**

You are right, in such a case **even** a simple program/model that outputs zeros for all the inputs would achieve an accuracy of more than 90%, **so** here **accuracy** is **not** a good metric to evaluate the model on.

You should go through the metrics **f1_score**,**recall**, and **precision** which are ideal for this type of problems.

Basically here we are interested in "out of those which are predicted positive, how many are really positive -precision" and "out of those which should have been predicted positive, how many are really predicted positive"

If my definitions seem confusing to understand, please got through the link below:

[f1_score/recall/precision](https://towardsdatascience.com/accuracy-precision-recall-or-f1-331fb37c5cb9)

Hope I was helpful